# How can I add conditions to my input in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

Take a look at this example.

```
export const Foo = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0)
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="" {state === 0 ? disabled : ""}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I'm trying to make the button disabled if `state` is equal to 0 and if not then the button will not be disabled. I don't know what is wrong and why it gives me this error: `'...' expected`

Comment: It should be `disabled={state === 0}`

Comment: react thinks you are trying to pass props. try this disabled={state}
and I would use true / false in this case

Answer (score 0):

react thinks you are trying to pass props. try this:

```
disabled={state} when state is true/false instead of 0/1
```

or

```
disabled={state === 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
 <input type="button" value="" disabled = {(state)? "disabled" : "" }/>
```

You must set "disabled" like if was a prop.

Answer (score 0):

React is expecting `props` that's why it is giving `'...' expected`.

what you can do is disable the button when the state is `0`. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-albattani-jbruu?file=/src/Foo.js)

`<input type="button" value="insert number" disabled={state === 0} />`